# Maven - creating and sharing packages between projects

Tags: maven

If I am working for a large organization, when is a situation where I would want to create my own Maven packages and share them with other projects inside my organization?

As I understand it a maven Package is just a maven project that you `mvn deploy`, then you can add the JAR to other projects. Is that it, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an *artifact repository* such as Artifactory or Nexus. Once you setup artifact repo, you'll have to configure your projects to deploy artifacts there. This is done through your `pom.xml` file. Then when you run `mvn deploy` the artifacts will be published to your repo.

Other projects can declare your artifacts as dependencies the same way you do with any other dependencies, but to resolve them they need to know about your artifact repo. This is done in `settings.xml`

Comment: Great thanks! You should check out Visual Studio Team Services Package Manager (mouthfull), it does kinda the same, but keeps it all connected to VS :)

Comment: Just to be clear, an artifact is an entire package? So 1 dependency = 1 artifact?